# Activity thread access

Tags: java, android

I have an app that needs to use a connection to a server over multiple sockets in different activities. I have set up a service which handles the connection throughout the program and holds all the input and output streams. The problem I am having is that i want to access the input streams from different activities using threads and im not sure how to do this without calling the streams each time from the service class in each activity which causes interference problems because multiple threads are retrieving the same data.

Does anyone have any ideas on how i should i should proceed, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: share some piece of code of yours.also narrow down the question too .

Answer (score 0):

well, if i got it correctly; your input stream object seems to be critical section. so you need a mechanism like semaphore that controls the usage of that stream object. otherwise, you can't know if there is an interference. Maybe i'm just wrong but it may lead you to a solution.